# Deleting Child from Parent, using Named query

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

Im kinda new to JPA, My question is, if I have the following parent- child relationship between two entities.  with this setting(as show below), is it okay to delete a child using just a named query ("delete from child where parent.id:id) and then not remove the from the parent children collection? I have tested this approach of just using named query and not deleting the children from the parent collection and it works just fine, but im trying to see if there are any major impacts when i delete them this way. The reason why im not removing them to the collection objects is because, Children is set to have NOT nullable field parent id. Thank you very much, and I look forward for your answers :)

```
public class Parent {

    ID.....

    parentName...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Child> children;
}

public class Child {

    id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = false)
    })
    private Parent parent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's perfectly OK to delete objects like this. orphanRemoval manages the rest for you.

Comment: Thank you asm0dey, you rock :)